# 70's or older story about a very dangerous planet

Tags: story-identification

People from Earth (I believe) settled for some reason I forgot on a planet where they were in constant danger. Everything was carnivorous, including plants, even trees.

In fact, the only way to survive a night was to climb into a certain tree. The tree was in fact also carnivorous but vey slow, so in the morning you could disentangle yourself from the tendrils it had started to extend to strangle you. But you had to be very careful before climbing into one because there was another species that looked very similar but was quick and would kill you.

One other danger were blobs of protoplasm that would roll and dissolve everything they met. These were easier to dodge, because they would more or less go in straight line but would deviate in the direction were the amount of food was largest. One could even get rid of them by trapping them along a line with a lot of food ending up in an empty place where they would starve.

I forgot almost everything else, I'm sorry...

Comment: Yes indeed, it was the same answer. The question was asked quite differently, though. I did not remember it was on Venus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [Parasite Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite_Planet)?

Wrong year, but it has some similarities:

You use the word 'carnivorous' but there's this line:

> the planet inhabited by native life forms, all of them parasitic to a greater or lesser degree

Also has the protoplasm you mention:

> a mass of fast-moving undifferentiated protoplasm that absorbs every living thing in its path, and whose touch is fatal to humans

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I found it on the Gutenberg project, and it is dead-on. Why "wrong year" ? I read it in the 70's. If it had been published later, that would be a contradiction, but I could hardly have read it when it was first published....

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant it was published in the 70's. I'm glad you found it! :)